# An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_***.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

This is my code

```
@if (ViewBag.last5Articles != null)
{
    List<Article> articles = ViewBag.last5Articles;
    foreach (var article in articles)
    {
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>@article.Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>@article.Body</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the start of the foreach loop. I can see that article is not null and it has a title and a body. But when I reach article.Body and I press F10 (Step Over) suddenly it became Null!!

> "An exception of type `'System.NullReferenceException'` occurred in
>   App_Web_ayg111kp.dll but was not handled in user code"

.
And when I finish debugging the yellow screen welcomes me with this message "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`".

Can anybody explain this problem to me please. I'm using .NET 4.5.2 and MVC 5.2

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace, please?

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer to my (same) problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412391/mvc5-razor-nullreferenceexception-in-model)

Try commenting out the next code line AFTER the error.

In your case, if you have

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>@article.Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>@article.Body</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
...more html stuff...

<p> @article.SomethingElse </p>
```

Try commenting out the '@article.SomethinElse' and see if it clears up the error

**From link:**
"Some times compiler could not point on exact lines having specific kind of errors in razor view may be because it could not keep their line number in stack trace or somewhere. I have found this case with Null Reference Exception and when null is passed in Url.Content.

So it helps to check the next C# statement in razor view when you did not get any error on the line shown by stack trace."