# System.NullReferenceException in App_Web_*.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nullreferenceexception

I am having an odd issue.

My MVC application seems to be working perfectly fine except for one view page.

The view page in question (Organization/Edit) gets a 'NullReferenceException' on every code item on the page. Whether it is **Html.TextBoxFor()** or **HTML.AntiForgeryToken()**.

I have my model, view, and controller laid out here on another question that i think is related -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475866/dropdownlistfor-null-reference-error

As you can see below, my **model** does have information inside of it. This screen capture was taken at the "**Return View("Edit", model)**" inside the controller.

**Exception Details**

```
- Source = App_Web_zu4jlld0
- StackTrace =    at ASP._Page_Views_Organization_Edit_vbhtml.Execute() in C:\Users\mtaylor\Projects\Check Im Here\mtaylor-branch\CheckImHere_v2\CheckImHereMVC\Views\Organization\Edit.vbhtml:line 16
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

[image]

**View**

```
@ModelType CheckImHereMVC.OrganizationEditViewModel

@Using Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Organization", FormMethod.Post)
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 'get errors here
 @Html.ValidationSummary(True) 'get errors here
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.organizationSub.subName, New With {.class = "span12"}) 'and errors here
End Using
```

One thing i notice is that if i comment out my 'textboxfor', my error will occur at the 'ValidationSummary()', if i comment out my 'ValidationSummary()', then my error will occur at 'AntiForgeryToken()'.

So it seems that the error just happens at the last possible code area.

Comment: Can you post the view, or at least the relevant parts?

Comment: Are you able to catch the exception to get more information on it? Not too familiar with this particular technology, but in the question you linked it said "Not handled in user code" so maybe handling the exception will at least shed some light on what is being referenced.

Comment: As far as i know there is not a way to do a "Try/Catch" scenario inside of the Razor View page. I see the error happening on the last "Html.Textboxfor" on the page (it's always the last one)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412391/mvc5-razor-nullreferenceexception-in-model)

For anyone finding this:

Try commenting out the next code line AFTER the error.

```
@ModelType CheckImHereMVC.OrganizationEditViewModel

@Using Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Organization", FormMethod.Post)
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
   @Html.ValidationSummary(True) 
   @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.organizationSub.subName, New With {.class = "span12"})
   @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.organizationSub.subTitle, New With {.class = "span12"})
   <img src="@Url.Content(Model.img.imgPath)" alt="IMAGES"/> 'commenting out this line fixed my issue
End Using
```

In the case above, i would get errors on the `model.organizationSub.subTitle`. If i commented that line out, i would get errors on the `model.organizationSub.subName` line. I then found the link mentioned and commented out the line **AFTER** all of my TextBoxFors. That fixed my issue.

From link: "Some times compiler could not point on exact lines having specific kind of errors in razor view may be because it could not keep their line number in stack trace or somewhere. I have found this case with Null Reference Exception and when null is passed in Url.Content.

So it helps to check the next C# statement in razor view when you did not get any error on the line shown by stack trace."

Comment: Another big thanks!  Had the same issue where a razor template was throwing a NullReference error when using a .resx file for strings even though the actual error line was the next .Net line of code trying to use a property on the Model.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. I wasted an hour trying to understand what was causing the NullReferenceException I was getting, when nothing was wrong with my TextBoxFor call...